# Obtaining pointer to python memoryview on bytes object

Tags: python, pointers, cython, memoryview, typed-memory-views

I have a python `memoryview` pointing to a `bytes` object on which I would like to perform some processing in cython.

My problem is:

- because the `bytes` object is not writable, cython does not allow constructing a typed (cython) memoryview from it
- I cannot use pointers either because I cannot get a pointer to the memoryview start

**Example:**

In python:

```
array = memoryview(b'abcdef')[3:]
```

In cython:

- `cdef char * my_ptr = &array[0]` fails to compile with the message: `Cannot take address of Python variable`
- `cdef char[:] my_view = array` fails at runtime with the message: `BufferError: memoryview: underlying buffer is not writable`

How does one solve this?

Comment: First question: how do you declare the `array` argument in you Cython function?

Comment: @PierredeBuyl I pass it in as a python object. Like so: Cython: `def myfunc(arr): pass`

Comment: Hi, after some doc-looking and googling, if all that you receive is a memoryview it seems hard to obtain read-write access. You should mention how the memoryview is created in the firstplace. If you can get a `Py_buffer` struct instead this might help. https://docs.python.org/3.5/c-api/buffer.html

Comment: @PierredeBuyl Many thanks for the `Py_buffer` struct hint! I came to the same solution. See the my answer to my own question below...

Answer (score 5):

Ok, after digging through the python api I found a solution to get a pointer to the `bytes` object's buffer in a memoryview (here called `bytes_view = memoryview(bytes())`). Maybe this helps somebody else:

```
from cpython.buffer cimport PyObject_GetBuffer, PyBuffer_Release, PyBUF_ANY_CONTIGUOUS, PyBUF_SIMPLE


cdef Py_buffer buffer
cdef char * my_ptr

PyObject_GetBuffer(bytes, &buffer, PyBUF_SIMPLE | PyBUF_ANY_CONTIGUOUS)
try:
    my_ptr = <char *>buffer.buf
    # use my_ptr
finally:
    PyBuffer_Release(&buffer)
```

Comment: exactly what i am looking for .. but what is buffer_view in your code ? do you mean "buffer" ?

Comment: I just tried this, and yes `buffer_view` should be `buffer`.

Comment: @ConradParker Thanks for the note. I copied the snippet from my code and in simplifying it, I messed with the variable names to make it clearer. I obviously missed one... Is the code snippet working for you as it is now?

Comment: @UdaiF.mHd Sorry I missed your message. I fixed the code as you suggested.

Answer (score 3):

Using a `bytearray` (as per @CheeseLover's answer) is probably the right way of doing things. My advice would be to work entirely in `bytearrays` thereby avoiding temporary conversions. However:

[`char*` can be directly created from a Python string](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/strings.html#passing-byte-strings) (or `bytes`) - see the end of the linked section:

```
cdef char * my_ptr = array
# you can then convert to a memoryview as normal in Cython
cdef char[:] mview = <char[:len(array)]>my_ptr
```

A couple of warnings:

1. Remember that `bytes` is not mutable and if you attempt to modify that memoryview is likely to cause issues
2. `my_ptr` (and thus `mview`) are only valid so long as `array` is valid, so be sure to keep a reference to `array` for as long as you need access ti the data,

Comment: Thanks. My problem is, I am given a `bytes` object. Thus I cannot switch to `bytesarray` without incurring the cost of instantiation. `char *` can be created from `bytes()` but not from `memoryview(bytes())`. Your suggestion fails with `TypeError: expected bytes, memoryview found`

Comment: Ah sorry - I misunderstood slightly. You can get the `bytes` back from the memoryview (no copying involved) with `array.obj` (Python >=3.3 only though) and then cast that to a `char*`

Comment: I tried that as well: it looses the offset of the memoryview. For `test = memoryview(b'abcdef')[3:]` `bytes(test) == b'def'` while `test.obj == b'abcdef'`. The only solution I found so far is the very verbose procedure in my answer below. - Though I would love to get rid of that horrible code-clutter.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `bytearray` to create a mutable memoryview. Please note that this won't change the string, only the `bytearray`

```
data = bytearray('python')
view = memoryview(data)
view[0] = 'c'
print data
# cython
```

Comment: Indeed. That's what I am doing right now. But instantiating a temporary `bytearray` object defeats the whole purpose of using cython to speed up my algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want cython memoryview to fail with 'underlying buffer is not writable' you simply should not ask for a writable buffer. Once you're in C domain you can summarily deal with that writability. So this works:

```
cdef const unsigned char[:] my_view = array
cdef char* my_ptr = <char*>&my_view[0]
```