# Cython: optimize native Python memoryview

Tags: python, cython, memoryview, typed-memory-views

I have a function (from an external Python library) that returns a `memoryview` object that I want to process in Cython.

Is there a way to convert it to a typed memoryview of bytes (without copy) for efficiency? And how would I do that? This doesn't work:

```
mv = memoryview(b'1234')
cdef char[:] *tmv
tmv = mv
     ^
------------------------------------------------------------

/home/me/.cache/ipython/cython/_cython_magic_f9f608355444e2d6828580906623cea8.pyx:3:6: Cannot convert Python object to '__Pyx_memviewslice *'
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41764244/2588654) if you have not already seen it.

Comment: Also, since python memoryviews are created from a bytearray, why not just pass the bytearray to cython instead?

Comment: @CodeSurgeon The `mv = memoryview(b'1234')` expression is opaque to me, i.e. `mv` is actually the result of a 3rd party libray function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41764244/5769463) linked by @CodeSurgeon is a possibility to do it. However, since Cython 0.28 we have a much cleaner way - the typed [read-only](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html#read-only-views) memoryviews:

```
%%cython
mv = memoryview(b'1234')
cdef const unsigned char[:] tmv=mv  #"const" is possible since Cython 0.28
```

Obviously you can only read from this memoryview (this is a Good Thing) and there is no copying involved.

You could also say: but this is `unsigned char` and not `char`! True - this is also a Good Thing: `bytes` are `unsigned char`s and the whole point of typed memoryviews that you aren't mixing up the types!

Another reason I think the linked solution is kind of dangerous - you have the whole power of C to shoot yourself in the foot, because it casts types and constness away. See for example:

```
%%cython    
def bad_things(a):
   cdef const unsigned char[:] safe=a
   cdef char *unsafe=<char *> &safe[0] #who needs const and types anyway?
   unsafe[0]=52   #replace through `4`
```

And now:

```
 >>> A=b'a'
 >>> bad_things(A)
 >>> print(A)   #take it Python - I pwned your immutability!
 b'4'
 >>> print(b'a')
 b'4'
 >>> #Help! What are you doing Python?
```

Because Python has a pool of small strings, which are immutable (or so the Python thinks), and we have changed the object to which `b'a'` is linked to `b'4'` we should brace ourself for funny results and happy debugging...

In overall, this is a no-brainer: stick to typed memoryviews which guarantee type- and constness-safety.